# storeTextPresent by ID selenium IDE

Tags: selenium-ide

---Jump down to my edit with a simplistic example---

I have searched Ad Nauseum, and spent hours getting this close, but still not solving my automation problem.
Here's the thing I convert the local paper from the print edition to the online edition through PDF's, the content gets pushed to the website and is not live, until I go in and edit some settings, a lot of these are redundant. so if I can get past this one point I'm golden and can shave literally hours off of the time it takes to do this work.

The paper has twenty or thirty writers, and the one_off_byline can vary a bit here is some examples.

id=id_one_off_byline value="Michael Reid"  however it may also look like the these next two or some variation thereoff even.

id=id_one_off_byline value="By Michael Reid"
id=id_one_off_byline value="By Michael Reid - Your Daily Paper"

I have used storeTextPresent to find Michael on the page. however the problem is there is another select value box on the page that contains every writers name in a selection box, which is what I'm actually trying to populate.  So here is what I have

```
<tr>
    <td>storeTextPresent</td>
    <td>Jeff</td>
<td>IsTextAppears</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>gotoIf</td>
    <td>${isTextAppears}</td>
    <td>Jeff</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeTextPresent</td>
    <td>Graham</td>
    <td>IsTextAppears</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>gotoIf</td>
    <td>${isTextAppears}</td>
    <td>Graham</td>     
   </tr>
<tr>
<td>label</td>
<td>Jeff</td>
 </tr>
<tr>
<td>label</td>
<td>Graham</td>
</tr>
```

Another way to phrase this I hope_*_*_

Form Field 1 (ignore syntax, I'm just setting up an example here) the id= is the important part in the two form fields.

```
<select name="select" id="pick_animal" value="">
  < option="the fast cat" id="1">
  < option="the fast dog" id="2">
</select>
```

Form Field 2

```
<input type="text" id="some_animal" value="the fast cat from dover">
```

I need to detect that `id="some_animal"` `contains cat`
so I can perform an action on the correct option in field 1.
I can do the second part just fine, I just can't detect "cat" in only the input with id "some_animal" 
storeTextPresent just looks for cat to exist anywhere on the page. ugh!!

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr>
    <td>storeTextPresent</td>
    <td>Jeff</td>
    <td>IsTextAppears</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>gotoIf</td>
    <td>${isTextAppears}==Jeff</td>
    <td>Jeff</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>goto</td>
    <td>END</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>label</td>
    <td>Jeff</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>something</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>label</td>
    <td>END</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>


Try like this.
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I don't know how to clarify this one part -  there are two byline fields, one called -